# (game-aids) vs. (tools)

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the functional difference between [game-aids](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-aids) and [tools](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tools)?

The latter has a well-defined excerpt and description:

> **Excerpt:** An online or offline tool used in preparing or running a RPG.
>
> **Wiki:** A device, software, online service, procedure or process used for a specific purpose in relationship to roleplaying games that is not part of the ruleset for a given rpg. Could be anything from "the Obsidian Portal campaign wiki website" to "the document called the Same Page Tool."

While the former only has an excerpt:

> Physical items or digital tools that help a game run more smoothly or enhance game play in some fashion.

"Tools" also has many more questions than "game-aids". Of the existing "game-aids" questions, most seem to be about Android apps, which would seem to fall squarely in the "tools" bailiwick.

Can these be merged? Or am I missing some nuance?

If they're not merged, shouldn't the Android questions in "tools" be re-tagged to "game-aids"?

Comment: The difference appears to be that both were created ages ago, but only one actually saw lasting adoption. This happens sometimes; good catch noticing it and bringing it to the community's attention. :)

Comment: I untagged four of the fifteen questions this has, they're generally the same thing except for some cases where someone was a just looking for aid with a game (not a physical object or etc). Tools is definitely a better name.

Comment: A significant number in either tag should also/instead be tagged with [tag:tool-recommendation]. I edited a few.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems like a solid case for synonymizing, and as of January 12, 2015, the community has agreed and the synonym has been made. `game-aids` now automatically remaps to `tools`.

Comment: I just cast the 4th vote - it's official now.

Comment: And now I've learned that synonyms definitely don't automatically merge the tag over. Good to know. \o/